# send messages one organization admin to another organization admin in hyperleger fabric

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, chaincode

I am building one POC using Hyperledger fabric,

Is it possible to send messages from one organization admin like money details to another organization admin and he sends the (agree/denied) message?

Answer (score 0):

You can work with multi organization model. Install chaincode on two organization peers and instantiate the chaincode over channel. Post Instantiation of chaincode you can invoke some transactions which will be distributed the orderer to every peer that is joined in the channel.

[In the below link you can expect a basic network for two organizations with two peers each.](https://www.blockchainexpert.uk/blog/how-to-deploy-hyperledger-fabric-network-from-scratch)